# How accurate is content sniffing in order to determine filetype?

Tags: filesystems, file-extension, mime-types, binary-files, hexadecimal

I need to identify the mime-type of extensionless files(document fileformats such as PDF, doc, docx etc), and I am wondering how accurate known file-signatures are?

What I will do is to create a map of the filetypes and their signatures. And then read the hex-values from each file. I will be using .NET for this and include the sniffing in my application. The problem is that I can't find any good library that does this in the .NET world and therefor I will try to write my own. According to me it should be pretty trivial due to the fact that I'm only interested in a small subset of the fileformats out there.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easy for some file types and difficult to impossible for others. Each file type will be different. There is not one spot in a file that identifies what type it is. For example, JPEG images have a very recognizable header with certain signatures, footer, and are easy to identify. But plain text files do not have any metadata attached to them at all. If you look at them in raw data, you see the text information is just mashed in between the previous file and the next file. If you have the file though, then you could possibly scan the whole file to make sure that it is ASCII or Unicode something.

It would take quite an effort to find an identification method like this for a significant amount of file types. You should look for a tool that's already available for this that can identify most of the types that are critical to you. [Here is a Windows program](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html) for example that does something like this and has 5,944 definitions of file types.

Can you provide more information on what you're trying to do? What is the magic number?

Comment: I'm only interested in various document file formats such as pdf, doc, docx etc.

Comment: See how that TrIDNet software works (it's actually written in .NET). It looks like the command line version may give you more flexibility in what you're trying to do as well such as working on many files at a time or changing or adding the correct extension. http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html